# How to create a new converting operator?

Tags: beamer, pstricks

The following trivial example illustrates my objective to create a converting operator `ptcm` (`pt` to `cm`). Unfortunately, it produces errors in TeX world as opposed to PS world.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt

\SpecialCoor

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](4,4)
\makeatletter
\pstVerb{/ptcm {\pst@number\psunit\space div} bind def}
\makeatother
\psline(!4 12 ptcm sub 0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error messages are:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> /ptcm {\pst 
                       @number\psunit \space div} bind def
l.17 \end{frame}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> /ptcm {\pst 
                       @number\psunit \space div} bind def
l.17 \end{frame}
```

How to create a new converting operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<argument> /ptcm {\pst 
                       @number\psunit \space div} bind def
```

shows you that `\pst@number` has been parsed as `\pst @number` because `@` is not a letter.

Beamer reads frame bodies as a macro argument so you need to put `\makeatletter` before the frame.